# How do I click the wrong answer to waste time?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm developing a game of questions and I already have the time set and wanted to know how to do to when clicking the wrong answer the time comes down and blink red so people see that they missed. 
The game is for a air of andoird(Then touchEvents)

```
//1.
var count:Number = 41;

//2.
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,count);

//3.
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);

//4.
myTimer.start();

//5.
function countdown(event:TimerEvent):void {
myText_txt.text = String((count)-myTimer.currentCount);
if(myText_txt.text == "0"){
  gotoAndStop(11)
}
}
```

Thank You!!

Comment: Don't use `currentCount` here, instead use your own variable.

Comment: how can i do this? i'm learning

Comment: Sorry, I am not very clear on what are you asking. Are you trying to simulate a wrong answer through code? Or I am reading the title wrong?

Comment: I have four answers but one of them is correct and I want the other 3 responses to click (TouchEvent) the I waste time

Comment: WrongAnwser.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
     fl_MouseClickHandler1);

     function fl_MouseClickHandler1(event:MouseEvent):void
     {
 trace("Falhou!");
     }

Comment: Can question be renamed to something "How to display countdown?" or something. Or I don't get it... Wait, Don't you want to use simply `myText_txt.text = String(count--);` in `function countdown(...` and something like `cont -= 10` in  `function fl_MouseClickHandler1(...` ?

Comment: Then rename the question to something like "Add time penalty when button clicked" and answer it.